# Tehillim for success in child-rearing

Tags: tefilla, children-parenting, tehilim-psalms

I have often been given the parenting advice, in addition to everything else done to care for and teach a child, to pray for the successful raising of the child to be righteous. As Tehillim is often regarded as the universal text of Jewish prayer, are there any specific chapters which have been identified as being particularly relevant or designated for praying for successful child-rearing?

I am interested in both chapters identified due to their meaning, or due to any "deeper" reasons.

Comment: Not _T'hilim_, but I understand that people have their kids in mind when saying "למען לא ניגע לריק ולא נלד לבהלה" (in ובא לציון).

Comment: Also not *Tehillim*; but, that is one of the kawanot of "*weshinantam levaneikha wedibarta bam*" in Qeri'at Shema'.

Comment: No source for this, but I suppose that if someone's concerned about rebellious children, the various Tehillim about David Hamelech's sons revolting against him would be appropriate.

Comment: Keep in mind that praying in one's own words is also a time-honored Jewish practice (in fact, that's all there was before the standard prayer service was implemented, and many rabbis, from Tannaim to Rabbeinu Yonah to Rebbe Nachman of Breslov to the Chafetz Chaim have advocated this practice).

Comment: In Yom HaYom, the Lubavitcher Rebbe teaches that daily Torah study in the home has an effect on the souls of his family. So ensuring one engages in Torah study daily should also help one's children be righteous: "Torah-study every day is crucial to life itself. This applies not only to the soul of the one studying but also to the souls of his family. For then (through Torah-study), the atmosphere of the home becomes an atmosphere of Torah and piety."

Answer (score 1):

[Chapter 127](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16348) and [128](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16349) both include prayers for successful children. [Chapter 119](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16340) is a general prayer for spiritual success, and would also be appropriate.

Comment: Can you provide a source for the final statement about 119? If it is based just on simple reading of the text, that seems to be true about many chapters of Tehillim.

Comment: I heard it somewhere, but don't remember where. It also would seem to me that 119 is especially appropriate, with its frequent mention of learning, as in "lamdeini chukecha" or "b'lamdi mishpitai tzidkecha" to name just two of dozens. Additionally, my answer was not intended to be exhaustive, nor exclude other chapters not mentioned.